# Can I install ubuntu 22.04LTS on my laptop

Tags: 22.04, system-info, cpuinfo

I have an old laptop Acer Aspire 5750g Intel core I5 2.5ghz and 4gb ram,and I would love to know If my machine supports the lastest ubuntu 22.04LTS

Comment: The short answer is yes. However, if it has an old 5400RPM HDD it'll be (very) slow. Replace with any current SATA SSD and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly yes. However, there is a very easy way to tell.

Boot it from a USB drive as if you were to install Ubuntu. However, choose "try it" and, well, try it before you commit to installing.

Test wifi connectivity, bluetooth, web browsing, watch a video, plug in your headphones. See if you like the performance.

If it works but the performance is not up to par, look at other desktop environments. Xfce, delivered by Xubuntu, is a popular choice.

(It's probably a good idea to replace the HDD with an SSD.)